# Sort group of records based on different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a four columns in table called recordings such as score, event_id, user_id and I would like to sum the score of recordings based on user id + event id, 
and then I would like to show the users of the different events sorted by Score.

So I have wriiten the below code

```
Recording.select("user_id,event_id,sum(score) as score").group(:user_id,:event_id).order("score DESC")
```

and the above query outputs the records based on the max score too min score like below

```
 #<Recording user_id: 4, event_id: 51, score: 64622>,
 #<Recording user_id: 3, event_id: 51, score: 5912>
 #<Recording user_id: 4, event_id: 31, score: 62>, 
 #<Recording user_id: 3, event_id: 48, score: 0>
```

But I want the re arrabge the results like below (users of the different events sorted by Score)

```
 #<Recording user_id: 4, event_id: 51, score: 64622>,
 #<Recording user_id: 4, event_id: 31, score: 62>, 
 #<Recording user_id: 3, event_id: 48, score: 0>,
 #<Recording user_id: 3, event_id: 51, score: 5912>
```

Comment: I am grouping the records with two columns, user_id & event_id

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. Your examples hardly clarify what your text fails to describe. Kudos to @PinnyM who seems to have figured it out after some more comments.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL, you can use a windowing function to do this:

```
select_sql <<-SELECT
  user_id, event_id, sum(score) as score, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, event_id ORDER BY sum(score) DESC) as rowNum
SELECT

subquery = Recording.select(select_sql).group(:user_id, :event_id).to_sql

Recording.select("*").from(Arel.sql("(#{subquery}) t")).
          order("rowNum, score DESC")
```

Comment: I never want to sort the records by event_id and score, I would like to re arrange the records based on score of each event.
Like belwo

Comment: What about the scores returned (64622, 5912, 62, 52) do you think is not in descending order?  What other logic do you want to use for ordering the scores?

Comment: I want to rearrange the records by max score of each event to min score, not only by score. Say If we have three events then the out put must be like the first 3 records must have the first 3 max values of each event and the second 3 records must needs to have the second 3 max scores of each event.

Comment: Ah, understood.  ANSI SQL doesn't give you an out-of-the-box way to do this, so you'll either need to use database-specific functions to achieve this, or resort it using ruby.  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, missed the PostgreSQL tag - updated with something that should work for you.